# What must I prepare for attending my first Encounters session?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league

I'm going to attend my first Encounters session next week at Dark Sphere in London.

What can I expect? I understand it's episodic and it will be midway through a story.
Are things wrapped up in each session?

Do I need to prepare a character or just show up with my PHB, dice and pencils and expect a suitable pregen to be available?

Answer (score 6):

I'm a DM for these, so here are some things you ought to know.

Encounters are episodic. Expect each full adventure to take about 3-4 sessions of 2 hours in length, depending on how quickly the group goes through it. NPCs from previous adventures sometimes show up in other adventures, so there is some continuity there. There is no telling if a group is in the middle of a story arc or not. The good news is that most of the adventures I've read can "easily" shoehorn characters in and out.

I suggest coming with two characters already made, using the standard array, of level 1 and 5. The level 5 character needs to be leveled using the average HP gain. Of course, one should bring their dice and pencils. No magic items, no rolling *anything* about a character without the DM present. If you have a DCI number, give that to the DM as well. If you don't, don't worry about it, the DM or event planner can get you one.

The DM or event planner may also give you a folio for your character, with a glossy character sheet. I suggest bringing your own character sheet because writing on that glossy one with pencil is difficult at best.  It also comes with a sticker and some explanation about things, like factions, but it can be quickly read. You should join a faction relevant for that storyline. This is something you can figure out within 1 minute of talking to your DM.

The level 5 character is for the places doing the *Elemental Evil* season, and the level 1 is for the *Tyranny of Dragons* season.

So, in short:

- Bring 2 characters, a level 1 and level 5.
- Bring your own character sheet, pencil, and dice.
- Never roll something for your character unless you're in front of the DM.
- Starting items from backgrounds and class.
- Feats allowed.

Answer (score 4):

The [Adventurer's League](http://dnd.wizards.com/playevents/organized-play) page has information on both Encounters and Expeditions.

> You can create a character and bring that character to games anywhere D&D Adventurers League is supported.

It also has a link to the [Adventurer's League Resources](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/events/adventurers-league-resources) page, which has some PDFs available for download: Adventurer's League Player's Guide, Log Sheet, and Character Sheet.

The Player's Guide has all the information you need.

> - Part 1 is about creating and advancing a character. It
>     covers what rules are allowed for characters and how
>     to advance characters after playing adventures.
> - Part 2 is about the campaign structure for the D&D
>     Adventurers League. It covers the different play
>     programs, what kinds of adventures are available,
>     and special rules for running and organizing D&D
>     Adventurers League events.
> - Part 3 contains resources and other information that
>     you might find handy. It also contains a list of frequently
>     asked questions.
>
> **What You Need to Play**
>
> In order to participate in D&D Adventurers League
>   games, you’ll need the following:
>
> - The D&D Basic Rules. This PDF document is available
>     for free on the Wizards of the Coast web site. It
>     contains all the basic rules of the game, and you can
>     create a character with it. More options for characters
>     are available in other products.
> - A character sheet. You can use an official D&D
>     Adventurers League character sheet, or any other
>     D&D character sheet that suits you.
> - A D&D Adventurers League adventure logsheet.
>     You’ll use this to record each session of play, keeping
>     track of your experience, treasure, and other notes.
> - A DCI number. This is an official Wizards of the
>     Coast organized play number. It’s obtainable at
>     public events; ask the organizer for one the first
>     time you play.